# Пакетное кадрирование изображений в Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

Есть несколько десятков изображений размером 700x431 пкс, на них просто сплошной цвет. Как можно запустить автоматическую обработку в ФШ, чтобы они стали 700х700 пкс? Поскольку там сплошной цвет, то их можно растянуть или кадрировать, неважно. Нужно просто чтобы каждая стала 700х700.

Comment: Почему именно фотошоп? Любая образованная смотрелка картинок с этим справится.

Comment: Соглашусь с предыдущим ответом, но, даже если нужен именно фотошоп, запишите один раз Action, а затем запускайте в пакетном режиме.